# No pythonw in Python 3.4 OS X 10.10?

Tags: python-3.x, osx-yosemite, updating

I am updating python on OS X 10.10 form the default installation 2.7 to the latest 3.4. I am following [this](https://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/) tutorial to replace the python framework and update all the `/usr/bin/by***` binaries. It all goes well until I notice that no `pythonw` binary exists in the 3.4 version. Is this something I can just ignore? Has `pythonw` been unified with `python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According python 3.4.3 in https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html:
"4.1.2. Running scripts with a GUI
With older versions of Python, there is one Mac OS X quirk that you need to be aware of: programs that talk to the Aqua window manager (in other words, anything that has a GUI) need to be run in a special way. Use pythonw instead of python to start such scripts.

With Python 3.4, you can use either python or pythonw."

I guess that's the reason why there's no pythonw in 3.4.3.

You can either delete the usr/bin/pythonw or link it to the python3, or older version you like.